# What is the role of excluded middle in classic forcing arguments?

Tags: set-theory, forcing, constructive-mathematics

I was doing an exercise out of Jech's "Set Theory," and noticed something somewhat interesting. This is exercise 14.7 in Jech.

> Let $D=\{q:q\Vdash\varphi\}$ be dense below $p$. If there exists some $r\leq p$ such that $r\Vdash\lnot\varphi$ then, by Theorem 14.7 (iia), for all $s\leq r, s\Vdash\lnot\varphi$, contradicting the density of $D$. So no $r\leq p$ forces $\lnot\varphi$ and,  by the same theorem, $p\Vdash\lnot\lnot\varphi.$ Thus, $p\Vdash\varphi$.

Don't worry if this proof is not entirely correct, that's not what I'm asking about. It was thrown together very quickly. Here's the interesting note. Excluded middle was used here. And it appears that for many of these arguments (but not for all!) that excluded middle is used. My question is about the interplay between constructive mathematics and forcing. It is very obvious to me that arguments like this *cannot* be used in constructive mathematics, but is there a scenario in which they can? Several exercises did not use excluded middle, so I wonder where exactly the line is.

How much modern set theory involving forcing can be done without assuming excluded middle?

Comment: Double negation plays a big role in classical (ahem) forcing because we want the resulting theory to be classical. You can define an intuitionistic forcing relation too, but then the result will be an intuitionistic set theory. Intuitionistic set theory is, in a sense, what topos theorists study, albeit in a very different language...

Comment: Cohen's original definition of forcing didn't have double negation elimination. If you read forcing papers from the early days of the theory you'll find that some people start with Cohen's definition, then throw in the double negation for simplicity, and then ignore Cohen's definition altogether.

Comment: I know this question was from a while ago, but I'm looking at this in confusion. I think my last sentence is wrong. $p\vdash \phi$ does not imply $p\vdash\psi$ if $\phi\equiv\psi$, correct? So, if $p\vdash\neg\neg\phi$, then $p$ doesn't necessarily force $\phi.$ How would I rectify this?